# Haskell: Join on State Monad

Tags: haskell

How to formally calculate/interpret the following expression?

```
runState (join (State $ \s -> (push 10,1:2:s))) [0,0,0]
```

I understand the informal explanation, which says: first run the outer stateful computation and then the resulting one.

Well, that's quite strange to me since if I follow the `join` and `>>=` definitions, it looks to me like I have to start from the internal monad (`push 10`) as the parameter of the `id`, and then do... hmmmm... well... I'm not sure what.... in order to get what is supposedly the result:

```
((),[10,1,2,0,0,0])
```

However how to explain it by the formal definitions:

```
instance Monad (State s) where  
    return x = State $ \s -> (x,s)  
    (State h) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s  
                                        (State g) = f a  
                                    in  g newState
```

and

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
join n = n >>= id
```

Also, the definition of the State Monad's bind (`>>=`) is quite hard to grasp as having some "intuitive"/visual meaning (as opposed to just a formal definition that would satisfy the Monad laws). Does it have a less formal and more intuitive meaning?

Answer (score 3):

If you specialise the type of `join` for `State s` you get:

```
join :: State s (State s a) -> State s a
```

so given a stateful computation which returns a result which is another stateful computation, `join` combines them into a single one.

The definition of `push` is not given in your question but I assume it looks like:

```
push :: a -> State [a] ()
push x = modify (x:)
```

along with some `State` type like

```
data State s a = State (s -> (a, s))
```

A value of `State s a` is a function which, given a value for the current state of type `s` returns a pair containing a result of type `a` and a new state value. Therefore

```
State $ \s -> (push 10,1:2:s)
```

has type `State [Int] (State [Int] ())` (or some other numeric type other than `Int`. The outer `State` function returns as its result another `State` computation, and updates the state to have the values `1` and `2` pushed onto it.

An implementation of `join` for this `State` type would look like:

```
join :: State s (State s a) -> State s a
join outer = State $ \s ->
  let (inner, s') = runState outer s
  in  runState inner s'
```

so it constructs a new stateful computation which first runs the outer computation to return a pair containing the inner computation and the new state. The inner computation is then run with the intermediate state.

If you plug your example into this definition then

```
outer = (State $ \s -> (push 10,1:2:s))
s = [0,0,0]
inner = push 10
s' = [1,2,0,0,0]
```

and the result is therefore the result of `runState (push 10) [1,2,0,0,0]` which is `((),[10,1,2,0,0,0])`

Comment: I understand the part of an inner state machine within an encapsulating state machine. Maybe I misunderstand it, but what is missing in your explanation is the transmission of `1:2:s` into the parameter of the state machine `push 10` i.e. `State $ \t -> ((),10:t)`. That "magic" is the work of join (if I understand it right). Without join, the two elements of the result tuple (specifically in the encapsulating state machine) don't "talk" to each other, i.e. the stack is not being sent as a parameter to the inner state machine. So I wanted to understand how join does that "magic". Hope I'm clear

Answer (score 3):

The classic definition of `State` is pretty simple.

```
newtype State s a = State {runState :: s -> (a,s) }
```

A `State s a` is a "computation" (actually just a function) that takes something of type `s` (the initial state) and produces something of type `a` (the result) and something of type `s` (the final state).

The definition you give in your question for `>>=` makes `State s a` a "lazy state transformer". This is useful for some things, but a little harder to understand and less well-behaved than the strict version, which goes like this:

```
m >>= f = State $ \s ->
  case runState m s of
    (x, s') -> runState (f x) s'
```

I've removed the laziness and also taken the opportunity to use a record selector rather than pattern matching on `State`.

What's this say? Given an initial state, I `runState m s` to get a result `x` and a new state `s'`. I apply `f` to `x` to get a state transformer, and then run that with initial state `s'`.

The lazy version just uses lazy pattern matching on the tuple. This means that the function `f` can try to produce a state transformer without inspecting its argument, and that transformer can try to run without looking at the initial state. You can use this laziness in some cases to tie recursive knots, implement funny functions like `mapAccumR`, and use state in lazy incremental stream processing, but most of the time you don't really want/need that.

Lee explains pretty well what `join` does, I think.

Comment: Comparing the lazy and non-lazy implementations, I can't see what makes the strict version stricter. Would you mind explaining that some more?

Comment: @amalloy, it's `let` vs. `case`. In the strict version, `>>=` case-scrutinizes the tuple before handing things over to `f`.

Comment: But aren't both of those just pattern-matching against a tuple? I was not aware that there was a difference between pattern-matching in a let vs pattern-matching in a single-clause `case` (for a type with only one constructor, anyway).

Comment: @amalloy, there is a difference, yes. `case x of pat -> e` (where `pat` is a pattern and not just a variable) is equivalent to `let !pat = x in e`. `let pat = x in e` is equivalent to `case x of ~pat -> e`.

Comment: @amalloy There is a difference, and it is precisely in the laziness of the pattern matching. To wit, `case`-ing on an `undefined` value will blow up, whereas binding it to a pattern in a `let` expression won't (until someone tries to evaluate one of the pattern variables).

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, it will blow up on an undefined value as long as the pattern is non-trivial *and matches on `data` and not `newtype`* (I missed that in my remark above).

Comment: @dfeuer Yep, subtleties abound when `_|_`'s around (hey, I'm a poet and I didn't even realise that I was making those words rhyme). I like to pretend it doesn't exist ;)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned following the definitions for `join` and `>>=`, so, let's try that.

```
runState (join (State $ \s -> (push 10,1:2:s))) [0,0,0] = ?
```

The definitions are, again

```
instance Monad (State s) where  
    -- return :: a -> State s a
    return x = State $ \s -> (x,s)
```

so for `x :: a`, `State $ \s -> (x,s) :: State s a`;  *(*) ---->*

```
    (State h) >>= f = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s  
                                        (State g) = f a  
                                    in  g newState  

join m = m >>= id
```

and `runState :: State s a -> s -> (a, s)`, i.e. it should be  *(*) <----*

`runState (State g) s = g s`. So, following the definitions we have

```
runState (join (State $ \s -> (push 10,1:2:s))) [0,0,0]
 = runState (State g) [0,0,0] 
     where (State g) = join (State $ \s -> (push 10,1:2:s))
                     = (State $ \s -> (push 10,1:2:s)) >>= id
                    -- (State      h                 ) >>= f 
                     = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = h s  
                                         (State g) = id a  
                                         h s = (push 10,1:2:s)
                                     in g newState  
                     = State $ \s -> let (a, newState) = (push 10,1:2:s)  
                                         (State g) = a
                                     in g newState  
                     = State $ \s -> let (State g) = push 10
                                     in g (1:2:s)
```

Now, `push 10 :: State s a` is supposed to match with `State g` where `g :: s -> (a, s)`; most probably it's defined as  `push 10 = State \s-> ((),(10:) s)`; so we have

```
                     = State $ \s -> let (State g) = State \s-> ((),(10:) s)
                                     in g (1:2:s)
                     = State $ \s -> let g s = ((),(10:) s)
                                     in g (1:2:s)
                     = State $ \s -> ((),(10:) (1:2:s))

 = runState (State $ \s -> ((),(10:) (1:2:s)) ) [0,0,0] 
 = (\s -> ((),(10:) (1:2:s))) [0,0,0]
 = ((), 10:1:2:[0,0,0])
```

. So you see that `push 10` is first *produced* as a result-value (with `(a, newState) = (push 10,1:2:s)`); *then* it is treated as the computation-description of type `State s a`, so is run *last* (not first, as you thought).

As Lee describes, `join :: State s (State s a) -> State s a`; the meaning of this type is, a computation of type `State s (State s a)` is one that produces `State s a` as its result-value, and that is `push 10`; we can run it only after we get hold of it.